# React Создание элементарного Video компонента

Tags: reactjs, видео

Пробую создать элементарный `<video>` элемент который бы автоматом запускал проигрывание видео после загрузки. Код выглядит следующим образом.

```
import React, {useRef, useEffect} from 'react';
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';

const VideoPlayer = ({src}) => {
    const videoRef = useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const videoElement = videoRef.current;

        if (videoElement) {
            videoElement.addEventListener('ended', handleVideoEnded);
            videoElement.play().catch((error) => {
                console.log('Auto-play failed:', error);
            });
        }

        return () => {
            if (videoElement) {
                videoElement.removeEventListener('ended', handleVideoEnded);
            }
        };
    }, []);

    const handleVideoEnded = () => {
        if (videoRef.current) {
            videoRef.current.play();
        }
    };

    return (
        <video width="100%" height="100%" controls className="video_block" ref={videoRef} autoPlay loop muted>
            <source src={src} type="video/mp4"/>
        </video>
    );
};


class App extends React.Component {


    render() {
        let videoSource = '/videos/start_long_1024x1366.mp4';
        return (
            <div className="field">
                <VideoPlayer src={videoSource}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const container = document.getElementById('root');
const root = createRoot(container);
root.render(<App />);
```

Видео файл находиться в директории `static/videos/start_long_1024x1366.mp4` Но при монтировании, оно почему-то не отображается, а файл не отображает атрибут `muted` Подскажите. что я делаю не так ?

Comment: Ну для начало видео импортируется не так ->  `let videoSource = '/videos/start_long_1024x1366.mp4';`

Comment: А как? Если оно находиться в `static/videos/` или надо куда-то положить ?

Comment: Нет, его надо импортировать так же как и другую сущность в реакте, как картинки импортируете, как mp3 файлы и т.д.